# show pause state when open a video in lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I'm trying to make a function that when you click a play button, the video is showed  center in page with lightbox effect. The problem is that i've set it to start playing, when you click the "open in lightbox play button" but the HTML5 video control show the play/pause button as "play" and not "pause". Is it possible to registrer if the video is playing it should add "pause" style from start etc.

link to live problem: http://instagib.dk/westring-kbh/

jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8rj09kL9/

I've tried something like this.

```
// light box effect with auto play
// show the popup outer
$("#play-index-video").click(function() {
    $(".video-popup-outer").show();
    $('.toggle-play-pause').addClass('pause');
    $("#showreel-video")[0].play();
});

// hide the popup outer
$(".close-video").click(function() {
    $(".video-popup-outer").hide();
    $("#showreel-video").load();
});

// toggle play / pause 
$('#play-pause').click(function() {
    $('.toggle-play-pause').toggleClass('play','pause'); //Adds 'a', removes 'b' and vice versa
});

// video functionality
window.onload = function() {    

    // Video
    var video = document.getElementById("showreel-video");
    // Buttons
    var playButton = document.getElementById("play-pause");
    // Event listener for the play/pause button
    playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (video.paused == true) {
            // Play the video
            video.play();
        } else {
            // Pause the video
            video.pause();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you make a working snippet for us to see ?

Comment: I have added a fiddle and a prototype on a live server. Hope that will help mate:)

Comment: I don't see any control on the video (FF34 on W8) ?

Comment: There should only be a play pause button. It is illustrated badly by red and blue background :P If you click on the blank button, it will open a video and play it automatically. The problem is, that when it opens, the play button is still active, not the pause.

Comment: I also don't see any controls. A video of some weird frog starts playing, and a blue/red square is in the middle, but no controls. When I click the button, nothing happens.

Comment: I have been inspired by basicagency's video :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed something in your code, since you already use jquery, I converted it all to jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // light box effect with auto play
    // show the popup outer
    $("#play-index-video").click(function () {
        $(".video-popup-outer").show();
        $('.toggle-play-pause').addClass('pause');
        $("#showreel-video")[0].play();
    });
    // hide the popup outer
    $(".close-video").click(function () {
        $(".video-popup-outer").hide();
        $("#showreel-video").load();
    });


    // Event listener for the play/pause button
    $("#play-pause").click(function () {
        $('.toggle-play-pause').toggleClass('play', 'pause'); //Adds 'a', removes 'b' and vice versa

        var video = $("#showreel-video")[0];
        if (video.paused) {
            video.play();
        } else {
            video.pause();
        }
    });
});
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/8rj09kL9/4/

Seems to work somehow.

Comment: Not too sure, maybe because it wasn't in `$(document).ready()`. I didn't really try to find the cause, just rewritten it.

Comment: Okay mate! But many thanks! It works as it should. lovely. Have a great weekend :)